# How keep a QWidget always on top?

Tags: qwidget, qmainwindow

I have two buttons on my QMainWindow. One to btnShowKb and another btnHideKb. When i press btnShowKb it shows an QWidget. I want this QWidget always to be on top of all windows till I press btnHideKb. When its on top, I want both QWidget and QMainWidget be activated.

Can anybody suggest on this?

Comment: You can't (reliably) steal focus in windows.

Answer (score 9):

Setting the setWindowFlags() with Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint is meant to help.

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt.html#WindowType-enum

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/widgets-windowflags.html

Comment: Thanks, also the code is shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855968/how-do-i-toggle-always-on-top-for-a-qmainwindow-in-qt

Answer (score 6):

Nokia was so yesterday...

New link:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html

and the line of code you might be looking for:

```
mainMenu->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```