# PyQt5 keep a QWidget always on top

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt, pyqt5

Can I force a child widget to stays on top when created inside my main window init function?

Its only working for me when the widget is created in app scope (as here [PyQt4 How keep a QWidget always on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892264/pyqt4-how-keep-a-qwidget-always-on-top/50892448#50892448)).

(Tested on Raspberry Pi OS)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
)

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        Widget = Ui_Widget(self)
        Widget.show()

class Ui_Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.Dialog)
        self.setWindowTitle("Widget")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.move(200, 150)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    # Widget = Ui_Widget(MainWindow)
    # Widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you mean that with the above code the `Ui_Widget` is shown *under* the main window? What OS are you using?

Comment: @musicamante yes, under the main windows on Raspberry Pi OS. Just tested on windows 10 where it works fine.

Comment: it could be a problem with the window manager. If you click on the child window and try to click on the main window again, does it gets on top again? Try adding `self.show()` *before* creating the `Ui_Widget` instance.

Comment: @musicamante your trick fixed it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably related to some bug or wrong implementation in the window manager (on Fluxbox it works as expected).

In any case, for consistency, you should not show a child widget *before* showing the parent (assuming that both have to appear at the same time): `MainWindow.show()` is called *after* the `__init__` is processed, and the result is that you're showing the child widget too early.

A basic workaround would be to call `self.show()` before showing the child widget, but it's usually considered good practice to *not* show widgets (including the instance itself) within the `__init__`.

A better solution would be to create a function that actually shows the parent widget and *then* creates and shows the child:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.resize(400, 300)

    def start(self):
        self.show()
        Widget = Ui_Widget(self)
        Widget.show()

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that using the `Dialog` flag for standard QWidgets is usually necessary for ***very*** specific situations. Most of the time, you could just use a QDialog and call `open()` instead of `show()`. You should also create a persistent reference for the child widget, as you might need to access it from the main window class.
Also note that classes named `Ui_xyz` are normally used for basic UI forms (those created with pyuic/pyside-uic), and variables should not have capitalized names, as only classes and constants use this convention (prefer `mainWindow` instead of `MainWindow`).